# does it create many function in memory if not using 'new' keyword in js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Suppose I have the following code:

```
function Human(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName,
    this.lastName = lastName,
    this.fullName = function() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}

var person1 = new Human("Virat", "Kohli");
var person2 = new Human("sddasd", "dasd");
```

What this code does is for each instance created, it creates those 2 properties and 1 method(fullName) again and again in memory, which is bad and should be avoided.

Now I have the following code. I have array of markers and i want to add same function(render function) to each marker.

```
for(let i=0;i<markers.length;i++){   
    markers[i].render = () => {
      let parentDiv = document.createElement('div');
      parentDiv.innerHTML = content;
      parentDiv.getElementsByClassName('openLocationClass')[0].onclick = () => openMarkerLocationPopupFunc(marker, data.workorder_id)
      if (showInstructions) parentDiv.getElementsByClassName('showInstructionsClass')[0].onclick = () => openShowInstructionPopupFunc(data.workorder_id)
      return parentDiv;
    }
}
```

**Question:**

Will this create copies of same functions in memory for each marker or how will this work? and if there's any way I can make this better? THe thing is I also get passed 2 functions in arguments and put them to onclick of the newly created div.

Answer (score 0):

> Will this create copies of same functions in memory for each marker...

Yes. Now, on any decent JavaScript engine, they'll all reuse the same underlying code, so it's "just" the extra function objects wrapping around that code that are duplicated. But yes, there's duplication. That's not necessarily a problem, though.

**If** `render` is called with `this` set to `marker`, you can avoid the duplication fairly easily:

```
function renderMarker() {
  let parentDiv = document.createElement('div');
  parentDiv.innerHTML = content;
  parentDiv.getElementsByClassName('openLocationClass')[0].onclick = () => openMarkerLocationPopupFunc(this, data.workorder_id);
  if (showInstructions) parentDiv.getElementsByClassName('showInstructionsClass')[0].onclick = showInstructionsClassClick;
  return parentDiv;
}

function showInstructionsClassClick() {
    openShowInstructionPopupFunc(data.workorder_id);
}

for(let i=0;i<markers.length;i++){   
    markers[i].render = renderMarker;
}
```

You might be able to get rid of that final arrow function in `renderMarker`, too, but I can't say for sure from the context. Would need to know what `openMarkerLocationPopupFunc` needs from the marker.

Comment: the thing is i only have data.workorder_id inside the for loop.  that's why I think my solution works fine. if I use your solution, renderMarker function won't know data.workorder_id.

Comment: @NikaKurashvili - You aren't setting `data` within the loop. The code above, at the same scope as your existing loop, will work (because `data` is in scope at that point).

Comment: Yeap, I was wrong. I also have the data (each time different) in the for-loop.

Comment: @NikaKurashvili - If `data` also varies per loop, then without further context, I don't immediately see a way to avoid creating functions (either directly as you're doing, or via `bind` which also creates a function).